# Set children of UIelement in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, parent-child

I want to code a button with two texblocks directly on the button in `WPF`.
I would do that in `xaml`, the code would look something like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource btnRaw}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="17" Width="17" ToolTip="Tooltip" Click="DeleteLastEntry">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{StaticResource brushLayerstackCoherent}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="14.8" Text="&#xE91F;" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold" Text="&#xE738;" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

However, I want to do that **NOT** in `xaml`, but programatically in `C#`.
I can create a `button` like this

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
...
```

But how do I add the grid inside the button?
An access via the `Children`-property is not present in `myButton`.

Comment: use the content property not children

Comment: The Grid is in the Button's Content. So create a Grid, add two TextBlocks to its Children collection, and assign it to the Button's Content property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     var button = new Button();

     var textBlock1 = new TextBlock();
     var textBlock2 = new TextBlock();

     var grid = new Grid();

     grid.Children.Add(textBlock1);
     grid.Children.Add(textBlock2);

     button.Content = grid;
```